# How to have an exclusive access to usb device on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, usb

I am using [Rah HID](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/rawhid.html) library to send packets to my [PCTX](http://www.endurance-rc.com/pctx.php) how ever not all the packets I sent are received. What am I missing here. how can I make it so that it doesn't skip any of the packet as it is very critical for my project. `

```
#ifndef Pctx_hpp
#define Pctx_hpp
extern "C" {
#include "hid.h"

}

#include <stdio.h>


class Pctx
{
public:

Pctx(int Vendoreid=0x0925,int productid=0x1299);

~Pctx();

bool transmite(int channel1,int channel2,int channel3,int channel4,int channel5,int channel6,int channel7,int channel8);

bool transmite(int channel, char value);


private:

int productid;

int vendorid;

 char buffer[32];


};



#endif /* Pctx_hpp */
```

``

```
#include "Pctx.hpp"


Pctx::Pctx(int Vendoreid,int Productid)
{
vendorid=Vendoreid;

productid=Productid;


buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 0;
buffer[2] = 0;
buffer[3] = 0;
buffer[4] = 0;
buffer[5] = 0;
buffer[6] = 0;
buffer[7] = 0;
buffer[8] = 0;
buffer[9] = 0;
buffer[10] = 0;
buffer[11] = 0;
buffer[12] = 0;
buffer[13] = 0;
buffer[14] = 0;
buffer[15] = 0;
buffer[16] = 0;
buffer[17] = 0;
buffer[18] = 0;
buffer[19] = 0;
buffer[20] = 0;
buffer[21] = 0;
buffer[22] = 0;
buffer[23] = 0;
buffer[24] = 0;
buffer[25] = 0;
buffer[26] = 0;
buffer[27] = 0;
buffer[28] = 0;
buffer[29] = 0;
buffer[30] = 0;
buffer[31] = 0;


rawhid_open(1, vendorid, productid , -1, -1);

}






Pctx::~Pctx()
{
rawhid_close(1);

}






bool Pctx::transmite(int channel1,int channel2,int channel3,int channel4,int     
channel5,int channel6,int channel7,int channel8)
{
 buffer[0] = channel1;
 buffer[1] = channel2;
 buffer[2] = channel3;
 buffer[3] = channel4;
 buffer[4] = channel5;
 buffer[5] = channel6;
 buffer[6] = channel7;
 buffer[7] = channel8;


 return 1==rawhid_send(0, buffer, 32, 200);
}






bool Pctx::transmite(int channel, char value)
{
buffer[channel-1]=value;

return 1==rawhid_send(0, buffer, 32, 100);
}
```

`When i run this it compiles but it doest actually sent all the packets it sometimes skips a few`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pctx.hpp"
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
#include "hid.h"


int main() {

Pctx radio;


radio.transmite(1, 120);


while (true) {

     radio.transmite(1, 200);

    cout<<200<<endl;

    sleep(5);

    radio.transmite(1,69);

    cout<<69<<endl;

    sleep(5);

}

return 0;

}`
```

Comment: `buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 0;
buffer[2] = 0;
buffer[3] = 0; // ...` this could be done in one line!